# Typescript while checking for duplicates, it considering empty space also

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I'm trying to remove duplicate values from my array using the below code:

```
for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++)
        obj[a[i]] = a[i]
      a = new Array();
      // Removing duplicates by checking each objects with keys.
      for (var key in obj)
        a.push(obj[key]);
```

It removing duplicates, but my problem is, it considering empty spaces also.

This is my array:

```
["Cardiologist", "Cardiologist", "Cardiologist ", "Neurologist ", "Neurologist "]
```

After removing duplicates I am getting like this

```
["Cardiologist", "Cardiologist ", "Neurologist "]
```

The value "Cardiologist" repeating because of empty space.  How can i get the exact result which i expect?

Comment: Notice an extra trailing space in `"Cardiologist "`

Answer (score 2):

You can use `string.prototype.trim()` to remove whitespace from the start and end of a string. I suggest you apply that prior to de-dupe.

```
myString.trim()
```

Example:

```js
    const arr = ["Cardiologist", "Cardiologist", "Cardiologist ", "Neurologist ", "Neurologist "];
    
    const trimmedArr = arr.map((v) => v.trim());
    
    console.log(trimmedArr);
```

Run that and you'll see any leading/trailing whitespace is gone. Now you can compare!